# ID checks while traveling from Stockholm to Tallin by ferry!

Tags: paperwork, sweden, sea-travel, estonia

Do they check IDs while traveling from Stockholm to Tallin by ferry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check in at a counter, yes. If you check in using a kiosk (using your two booking codes, one 8-digit and one 4-digit code), then no.

Comment: Hmm... I been given one 7-digit code (Booking number). Does this vary according to different shipping lines, perhaps?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Yes, this is for Tallink Silja

Comment: Does that mean if I check in using the kiosk I won't have to pass the counter​?

Comment: 100% correct, the kiosk spits out the boarding card which you scan at the entrance gate to get onto the ship. This is also the keycard for the cabin

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks mate, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

IDs typically aren't checked when travelling between Schengen countries.

However the border officials are fully within their rights to ask to see your ID so you should carry it anyway.

Going from Stockholm to Tallin I'd say a random check is less likely than the reverse however you should still have ID just in case.

I have been checked when going from Stockholm to Aland and on the Helsingor-Helsingborg ferry.

Comment: Who checked you? The ferry staff or the border control officers?

Comment: Border checks in Sweden are carried out by the police, and they're not normally even present at the port. While Sweden has introduced spot checks, these are limited to the Öresund bridge and occasionally ferry ports for pax arriving from Denmark/Germany

Comment: aland it was someone working for the ferry company iirc. Though Aland has a weird legal state that may be something to do with it. Helsingborg it was an official of some sort, can't recall if he was normal police or something different.

Comment: When I was going from Denmark to Sweden by bus via [Øresund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98resund_Bridge), the check was carried out just after the bridge by Sweden Police.

Answer (score 1):

I will travel this route on the Viking line in early July. The booking confirmation that they emailed me included this: "Please remember to bring a valid ID on your trip. Please remember to have your passport at hand."

**Added:** I tried to, but was not allowed to, pass through the gate after scanning my boarding pass. An alert sounded, and I was required to show my passport.